# Is there an English word for a fear of salt?

Tags: single-word-requests, phobias

While terms like arachnophobia and agoraphobia are well-known, after a quick internet search I wasn't able to find a term for a fear of salt.

Does one exist, and if so what is it?

P.S. If this isn't the right stack exchange site to ask such a question, please point me in the right direction!

Comment: You want to ask all English-specific questions on the site dedicated to English, [ELU.se] (unless you're trying to *learn* English as a foreign language, then you want to use [ELL.se]).  PS: one gloss of *halophobia* is "*inability* [fear] *of plants to grow in salt-rich soil*".

Comment: "Slug Syndrome."

Comment: The Greek root is _hal-_, and the Latin root is _sal-_; cognates with initial PIE *s- tend to show up in Greek with initial _h-_: _super-/hyper-, sub/-hypo-, sexa-/hexa-, septa-/hepta-_ etc.

Comment: All these Greek derived names for phobias are less worthwhile than stamp-collecting or train-spotting IMO. I suggest 'salt-phobia'.

Comment: Why not "salt-fear"? That's what William Barnes would suggest. He purged all non-English words from his English and then wrote a grammar (_An Outline of English Speech-craft_, 1878) of it, in it. Very interesting, didn't catch on, alas. However, it's out of copyright and [available on the web](https://books.google.com/books?id=K60VAAAAYAAJ&hl=en).

Comment: Well put, @chaslyfromUK.  A colleague once told me that he was afraid of spiders, adding that he was an arachnophobe.  I guess he thought that was an explanation, but he'd just told me the same thing in Greek.

Comment: @DavidGarner The "explanation" implies that it's an irrational fear, as opposed to a more specific reason, such as being allergic.

Comment: Fair point, @Barmar.  It's unfair to tease anyone with an irrational fear, but my point was that he probably thought that expressing it with a Greek-based word made his fear more respectable than if he'd just said he was afraid of spiders.

Comment: I'm with @chaslyfromUK BUT I wouldn't use a hyphen: salt phobia.  (My son has a button phobia, and I'm not going to use a hyphen for that one.)

Comment: Are there cases of salt phobia?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK, I have nothing against Greek (so much of English is Greek
anyway, that some knowledge of Greek must be considered essential to full
English literacy); but _if_ one wants to avoid Greek, then Lawler
is undoubtedly right that it must be _salt-fear:_ _salt-phobia_ just
looks ignorant and clumsy.

Answer (score 5):

halophobia, from the Greek ἅλς, ἁλός. cf. halomorphic, halophytic. See also O.E.D. halo-, comb. form, according to which the pronunciation is: /hæləʊ-/.

If I am not mistaken, the word denoting fear of x = the Gr. root of x + o + phobia.

natrophobia is not correct, as the Gr. word is νίτρον, giving nitrophobia. But νίτρον is sodium carbonite, not s. chloride.

Answer (score 0):

I would use **Natrophobia**. Natro coming from natron l (a salt) and phobia (fear). What I am wondering is whether by salt you mean the entire range of salts or just table salt (NaCl). Natron is not a synonym for table salt but a basic salt.

Answer (score 0):

I would use **natriophobia** or **natriphobia** from the new latin natrium. Scientific words relating to salt generally use this root rather than the Greek (e.g. natriuresis).

Answer (score -1):

On the surface and subterranean regions on planet earth the definition of sodiuphobia is the fear of salt or the fear of high sodium.this is me and my friend hiding from salt because of the irrational fear of getting high sodium levels in our blood.